# Can't receive Jira server plugin changes locally

Tags: java, jira, jira-plugin

Just started developing Jira server plugin with an official tutorial: 
https://developer.atlassian.com/docs/getting-started/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/modify-the-plugin

Changes I'm applying to the myPlugin project, do not appear on my local Jira instance. I've added Web Section and Web Item module with SDK, as written in the tutorial, and I can see these modules enabled in my local Manage add-ons page, however, I can't see the new drop-down menu at Jira instance.

I've also tried to clone project, that was proposed by Atlassian: 
https://bitbucket.org/serverecosystem/myplugin This project works fine. everything is in place: modules are enabled and there are new web section and web item.

I've tried to compare my pom.xml and atlassian-plugin.xml with files from Atlassian repo. The only difference is in AMPS version. I've tried to change it but did not receive any changes again.

So, the question is: what may be the reason for such behavior? Any help or direction to look at is very appreciated.